# Searching for data that matches 2 columns in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of Model (Numbers) and the part (Numbers) they are in this format:

```
Model No.    Part No.   Quantity  
12345 ....... 23 ...........2  
12345 ....... 36 ...........3  
67890 ....... 23 ...........1  
67890 ....... 28 ...........7  
.....
```

I am trying to create a 2x2 Matrix from this data. The Rows will have unique model numbers and Columns will have unique part numbers. The value in the matrix will correspond to the quantity of parts. The list is around 4000 rows, has around 150 different Models and around 500 unique part numbers. Each Model can have upto 40 parts that go into it.

Any suggestions on how I can create this matrix? I am not very familiar with coding/vba so guidance will be appreciated. It would be wonderful if excel formulae do the trick. Want to reduce the effort to minimum!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could use a pivot table to do this.

1. Select the range if your table.
2. Go to `Insert` > `Pivot Table` then OK.
3. Drag the fields in the appropriate 'boxes' like this:

[image]

Is that what you're looking for?